# Probability of min count in random selection

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given the following scenario:

- 5 items out of 50 are selected randomly without repetition
- The experiment is repeated 1000 times (Bernoulli)

What is the probability that **any** item gets selected at least 30 times in total throughout all 1000 experiment runs?

Is this formula somehow getting close?

$$
\sum _{i=0}^5 \left(\sum _{j=30}^{1000} \binom{1000}{j} \left(\frac{1}{50-i}\right)^j \left(1-\frac{1}{50-i}\right)^{1000-j}\right)
$$

Comment: I apologise for blatantly navigating around proper terminology, English is not my native language…

Comment: Not exactly following the formula as I may misunderstood the scenario here. Consider for a particular item, it has a $5/50$ chance to be selected in each experiment, so the number of times selected in $1000$ independent experiments for this particular item follows $\text{Binomial}(1000, 1/10)$, and you can sum the pmfs to get the probability for this particular item. If you means at least one item being selected at least $30$ times, then the probability is $1$ by pigeonhole principle.